# Html & css marquee

Tags: html, css, wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages

My html gets cuttoff when using css to animate the marquee.

```css
.marquee {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    padding-top: 1px;
    overflow: visible;
    white-space: nowrap;
    background-color: #000000;
    animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes slide {
    0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
    Use code SUMMER50 for a $50 discount on orders over $300!
</div>
```

I tried moving the text all the way to the right trying to get it to start off the screen and I added a `margin-left: 600px;` just trying to get the marquee box to start off screen and animate from right to left.

In result my code gets cutoff on the iphone. idk why. here is the website https://614.productions/

Comment: Please format your question properly.

Answer (score 2):

Try replacing percent value in the `translate` functions with `vw` (viewport width) units.

This is because 100% of `translate` is calculated using the element size. So in your site, the element width of 100% is not the width of the screen, it is about 600px, so `translateX` is likely to translate about 600px.

Anyway, I don't recommend using the marquee functionality because it has very bad UX: it distracts users, and it is hard to read text that is in constant movement.

```css
.marquee {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  padding-top: 1px;
  overflow: visible;
  white-space: nowrap;
  background-color: #000000;
  animation: slide 10s linear infinite;
  color: white;
  text-align: center; /** better with this */
}


/** here is the change */
@keyframes slide {
  0% { transform: translateX(100vw); }
  100% { transform: translateX(-100vw); }
}
```

```html
<div class="marquee">
  Use code SUMMER50 for a $50 discount on orders over $300!
</div>
```

Comment: you think I should just make it static text? or is there anything I can do to make it pop out a little?

Comment: The most common element for that purpose/context is to create a banner, requires a good edited image, it's more like a UI/UX task